# Banner Changer is not working. How to solve?

Tags: javascript

I want to make bot which is changing banner, but this code is not working. Who can help?

````
        if (updateBanner == true) {
            var userCount = client.guilds.cache.get('866048794272595999').memberCount;
            var canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(960, 540);
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var Image = Canvas.Image;
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = 'dm.png';

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.font = '40pt Acrom Light';
            ctx.fillText(userCount, 500, 500)
            canvas.createPNGStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'font.png')))
            client.guilds.cache.get('866048794272595999').setBanner("font.png");
            console.log(`Загрузка изображения`);
            updateBanner = false;
        } else console.log('Обновление не требуется!');
    }, 600000);```
````

Comment: What exactly is not working? We need more details.

Comment: Bot is not changing the banner

Comment: So does it get called? Did you set a break point and walk through the code? Are there errors?

Comment: No errors. I can send u full code